Characterize Bifurcation in Nonlinear ODE
Consider the mapping
$F: H^1_0(\mathbb R_+) \times \mathbb R \to H^1_0(\mathbb R_+)$
for an ODE with solutions $(u_E,E)$ that satisfy
$$ F(u_E,E) = 0.$$
Suppose there is a solution iff $E > E_0 > 0$, and the solution is unique (up to some symmetry transformation) for $E \in [E_0, E_0 + a]$. Additionally, as $E \downarrow E_0$, $\left. D_u F\right\vert_{(u_E,E)}$ has an eigenvalue that approaches zero, but there is no solution at $E=E_0$. We observe also as $E_k \downarrow E_0$ that $\|u_{E_k}\|_{L^2}^2 \to N_0 > 0$ and $u_{E_k} = s_0(x - x_k) + v_k$ where $v_k \to 0$ in $H^1$ and $x_k \to \infty$.
Is there a characterization of such a bifurcation, whereby the solutions bifurcate as a mode with center coming in from $x = \infty$? This doesn't seem to match any traditional bifurcation type (saddle-node, pitchfork, etc.) that I have seen, but I hope to have some literature to compare my results with, if possible.

I don't understand a point in the question: if the $u$ is a function of one variable and a parameter $E$, how can it be the solution of a PDE? Or am I missing something?

@DanieleTampieri sure, thanks. Updated.
